# Using ajax to get url but for some reason it doesnt

Tags: javascript, ajax, get

```
function getCity(city){
 $.ajax({
        url: 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text="' + city + '")',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
    var humi = data.query.results.channel.atmosphere.humidity;
    var wind = data.query.results.channel.wind.speed;
    var temp = data.query.results.channel.item.condition.temp;
        temp = Math.floor((temp - 32) * (5 / 9));
        wind = Math.floor(wind*1.609344);
        $('#temp-get').html(temp+"C°");
        $('#humi-get').html(humi+"%");
        $('#wind-get').html(wind+"km/h");
        },
        error: function(){
        $('#temp-get').html("Couldn't get info");
        $('#humi-get').html("Couldn't get info");
        $('#wind-get').html("Couldn't get info");    
        }
    });
}
```

It always returns couldn't get info and if i comment out error and remove success it still doesn't return anything, but if i use:
`$.get('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text="' + city + '")&format=json'`,
it returns info as it should but then i can't use success and error to check if i got info as i know

Comment: (1) Read the code formatting instructions next to the box where you write a question. (2) Open the developer tools in your browser and look at the Console. There will probably be an error message telling you what the problem is. (3) Open the developer tools in your browser and look at the Network tab: That will tell you what, exactly, the browser is requesting and what the server is sending back.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jQuery's [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).

The third parameter for `$.get` IS Ajax `success` and `.fail()` for error.

So, you could pass in the third parameter like so:

```
$.get('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text="' + city + '")', 
       {}, 
       function(data){console.log(data);})
  .error(function(){console.log("ERR");})
```